# ADI Peaceman and Rachford Method

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have read book Numerical Solutions of PDE by Morton and Mayers.

The Crank Nicolson method have the numerical scheme like this.
[image]

Now I read next page, there is a new method, namely Peaceman and Rachford method. In this book said that PR method is modification of Crank Nicolson Method, like this

[image]

What the modification of (3.11) to (3.13)? How to obtain (3.11) to (3.13)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coefficients of $U^{n+1}$ and $U^n$ both contain the term $\mu_x\mu_y \delta_x^2 \delta_y^2 / 4$ in the expression (3.13), which was absent in (3.11). It's therefore not possible to obtain (3.13) from (3.11). Nonetheless, without any additional information, I guess that this addition being of fourth order ($\delta_x^2 \delta_y^2$) with respect to discretization, it doesn't affect the convergence properties of the numerical solution.